# Using ajax with unique ids

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, get

Hey guys I need to have ajax on my website but I have no clue of javascript. I'm building my very first website and all I know is a bit of PHP and HTML/CSS.
Anyway, what I need is to send to a *different.php* an ID using the `GET` method and I've done that page to display json with the response.

```
"success":"true";
"success":"duplicate";
"success":"false",
"reason":"theReason";
"premium":"error";
```

Those are the responses I can get.
What I want is 3 different behaviours depending on the message.
I will write in PHP to try to make it more clear.

```
if(success == true OR duplicate){    
    // change div bg color: green;    
    // hideDiv after 0.2seconds;    (want to give time for users to see the green);    
}else if(success == false){    
    // change div bg color: red;
    // alert: "theReason";
}else{    
    // "premium":"error";    header('Location: page.php');
}
```

Since all the relevant Divs are loaded from a database the ID to send to *different.php* can be easily found. I can do

```
<div id="123">
```

if it makes it easier or

```
<a href="different.php?id=123">Submit</a>
```

I know this is not very good question but I was reading about AJAX and I didn't understand it.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery $.get - it is very easy to use. The "header page.php" would be `location.replace("page.php")`  in JS

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: Yes, I want to make that PHP code into Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that.
1. Download jQuery:
http://jquery.com/download/
2. Include the script you downloaded into your webpage:

```
<script src='/path/to/downloaded/jquery'></script>
```

3. Then it all depends on when you want your ajax to be executed. Let's assume you have a link that should load your data. Then you can do it like that:

HTML code

```
<a id='#mylink' data-id='123>My link</a>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
$('#mylink').on('click', function() {
    $.get('different.php', {'id': $(this).attr('data-id')}, function(resonse) {
        // response variable contains your JSON from different.php script, so write here you JavaScript code that uses it
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps.